# The constructor <Class> is undefined. Can't use <super(arg)> in java

Tags: java, constructor, undefined, super

I'm a complete newbie in Java. I can't understand why Java doesn't allow me to use the keyword super(arg).
OBS: Design05C is subclass of Design05.

```
public class Design05C extends Design05 {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Design05C(char typeCoord, double xCartesian, double yCartesian) {
        super(typeCoord);
        this.x = xCartesian;
        this.y = yCartesian;
    }   

    //Instance methods **************************************************    
    public double getX()  
    {
        if(typeCoord == 'C') 
            return x;
        else 
            return (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(y)) * x);
    }   

    public double getY()
    {
        if(typeCoord == 'C') 
            return y;
        else 
            return (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(y)) * x);
    }    
}
```

This is the superclass, Design05:

```
public class Design05
{
    public char typeCoord;
    public Design05C designC;
    public Design05P designP;

    public Design05(char type, Design05C dCartesian, Design05P dPolar)
    {
        if(type != 'C' && type != 'P')
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        typeCoord = type;
        designC = dCartesian;
        designP = dPolar;
    }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Show us the class Design05

Comment: Check if your `Design05` class has a 1 parameter constructor, of `char` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no constructor in Design05 class which takes a single char argument. You will have to change your call to super constructor from this

```
  super(typeCoord);
```

to this

```
  super(typeCoord, xCartesian, yCartesian);
```

Then your code would work. Try.

EDIT:

Your design itself is incorrect. You cannot add the subclasses objects in the constructor of the super class. This wont work. Remove the subclass objects from the constructor.

If you want to add the subclass objects inside the super class object, then keep references of them and initialize them after the construction of the objects. And not in the constructor.

Comment: It says "The constructor Design05(char, double, double) is undefined". But even if it worked, I think I can only call "typeCoord" on super() because the superclass doesn't have neither xCartesian nor yCartesian. Those are in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Possibility reason is,

`super` class `Design05` class don't have a constructor which takes a char as argument.

**Edit**

Since the constructor

```
 public Design05(char type, Design05C dCartesian, Design05P dPolar)
    {
        if(type != 'C' && type != 'P')
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        typeCoord = type;
        designC = dCartesian;
        designP = dPolar;
    }
```

taking three argument ,but you are passing only one parameter  here is

`super(typeCoord);`

So add another constructor to your super class such that it takes  `char` alone  also.

```
public class Design05
{
    public char typeCoord;
    public Design05C designC;
    public Design05P designP;

    public Design05(char type, Design05C dCartesian, Design05P dPolar)
    {
        if(type != 'C' && type != 'P')
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        typeCoord = type;
        designC = dCartesian;
        designP = dPolar;
    }

   public Desgin05(char type){

   typeCoord = type;

  }
}
```

Comment: Suprisely it has. I edited the question and put Design05 there.

Comment: No No, there are three arguments it's taking,you are passing only one

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you! But now it gives the error on this new constructor that says "Return type for the method is missing".

Answer (score 0):

test that Design05 has created this contructor

```
public Desgin05(char value){

this.value = value;

}
```

if there isn't constructor, you need to create.

Comment: There is. Now you can see Design05 in the question.